# $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}t-x(t)=0\ ?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, asymptotics, dynamical-systems

Let $\displaystyle\cases{
x'=\frac{t-x}{1+t^2+x^2}  & \cr
x(1)=1 
}$ be the Initial value problem, prove or disprove $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}t-x(t)=0$

We've already proved that: for $t>1, x(t)<t$, but it is also true that $x'>0\iff x<t$, so the question is legitimate, we're not allowed to solve the problem, and read it from the result. Wolframalpha says no, I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(t) = x(t) - t$.  Then the equation becomes

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{du}{dt} = 1 - \frac{u}{1+2t^2 + 2tu + u^2}\\
u(1) = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then since the denominator $1+2t^2 + 2tu + u^2$ is always positive (and in fact greater than 1),$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} u(t) = 0 \ \Rightarrow \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{du}{dt} = 1$$ 
which contradicts various theorems about ilmits and derivatives; pick the one you have learned in your course.

So the limit of $t-x$ cannot be zero.

Comment: If $\lim u(t)$ and $\lim u'(t)$ are finite then $\lim u'(t)\overset!{=}0$, right ?

Comment: True, if by "finite" you mean finite and non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $\lim t-x(t)=0$, then there exist "arbitrary large values" such that $x'(t)\geq 1/2$. However for sufficiently large $t$, if $t-x(t)\leq 1$ (which forces $x(t)\geq t/2$), then
$x'(t)\leq 1/(1+t^2+t^2/4)\ll 1/2$...

Comment: can you explain the 1st sentence, why is that true ?

Comment: $\lim t-x(t)=0$ implies $\lim t/x(t)=1$, hence $x(t)$ is asymptoticly linear (with slope 1).